How to modify an array using numpy.where() based on a conditional statement?
I am trying to use numpy to generate an array of 60 random numbers (either 0 or 1, i.e. a Bernoulli subset of the binomial). This first part of the code works fine as it generates 60 random (0 or 1 values based on a given probability).
However, I then want to modify the values of this first stored array (saved in 'result') using numpy.where() so that for each element if it is 1 it becomes a "Z" and if it is 0 then it is replaced with another random binomial number.
Many iterations of the code show that it is replacing 1s with "Z"s but it is not modifying any of the zeros as eventually I should find some new 1s where zeros were and this is not happening.
import numpy

n = 50 #The number of times to repeat the run
p = 0.1
count = 0

# Day one of the simulation
result = numpy.random.binomial(1, p, 60) 
print (result)
for ele in result: 
        if (ele == 1):
            count = count +1
print ("Number Infected:", count)

# Create the matrix to track who is infected
result = numpy.where(result == 1, "Z", numpy.random.binomial(1,p*count))
count = 0
for ele in result: 
        if (ele == 1):
            count = count +1

# while count > 0: EVENTUALLY YOU WILL LOOP TO THIS CONDITION #
# ith day of simulation #
#for ele in result:
#        if (ele == 0):
#            ele == "X"
#        else:
#            ele == "I"
print(result)
print("Number Infected:", count)

CURRENT RESULT:
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
Number Infected: 5
['0' 'Z' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'Z' '0' '0'
 '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0'
 '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' 'Z' 'Z'
 '0' '0' '0' 'Z' '0' '0']
Number Infected: 0


Which line are you asking about? Is it this one? result = numpy.where(result == 1, "Z", numpy.random.binomial(1,p*count))

Also, if you want to use numpy you should use a number instead of "Z". Once you use a string your change the datatype of your array and no longer get any advantage of numpy (it's called numpy for a reason). If you keep the data as numbers, your counting loops can be vectorized, which will be much faster for larger arrays.

Jared,  that is the correct line and I used Z just to make it visible to me since using 1s in this case would just return the same 1s and I would  not be sure it was working. Thanks!

Use a different number, like 2. Like I said, if you're going to use numpy you should keep it numerical.

TL;DR: You forgot to put the size of result in the call to numpy.random.binomial. Use numpy.random.binomial(1, p*count, 60) or, better yet, numpy.random.binomial(1, p*count, result.size). Also, since you assigned a string to the numpy array, the result array will only contain strings and, therefore, the result of ele == 1 will always be False, since no string can be equal to the int 1.

The issue arrises from the usage of numpy.where and numpy.random.binomial. From the documentation of numpy.where, the function will check where condition is true and will draw from either from x, if the value is truthy, or y, if the value is falsy.
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 2, 4],
    [0, 3, 6]
])

condition = (data > 0)
'''
condition == np.array([
    [False, True, True],
    [False, True, True],
    [False, True, True]
])
'''

x = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

y = np.array([
    [-1, -2, -3],
    [-4, -5, -6],
    [-7, -8, -9]
])

'''
np.where(condition, x, y) == np.array([
    [-1, 2, 3],
    [-4, 5, 6],
    [-7, 8, 9]
])
'''

However, it won't really draw from x nor y, but rather from the the resulting arrays from the broadcasting of x and y to the shape of condition. This means that, since you've passed "Z" as a value, it will be broadcasted to the shape of result == 1 before drawing the value. To learn more about broadcasting in numpy, here's the documentation.
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 2, 4],
    [0, 3, 6]
])

condition = (data > 0)
'''
condition == np.array([
    [False, True, True],
    [False, True, True],
    [False, True, True]
])
'''

x = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

y = -1

'''
np.where(condition, x, y) == np.array([
    [-1, 2, 3],
    [-1, 5, 6],
    [-1, 8, 9]
])
'''

So, what's the issue, then? The issue arrises when you use numpy.random.binomial, but you don't pass a shape. From the documentation of numpy.random.binomial, if you don't pass the optional argument size, it will default to giving you a single sample from the distribution (provided the parameters n and p are scalars, which is the case for this problem). This means that the single sample you get from numpy.random.binomial will be broadcasted to the size of condition in numpy.where and will be the only value drawn to replace where condition is falsy. Since the value from numpy.random.binomial is random, you can run your snippet of code a few times to notice that sometimes you get ['0', 'Z', ..., '0'] while sometimes you get ['1', 'Z', ..., '1']. To fix this, you just need to pass to numpy.random.binomial the size of result.

I did fix the code, while introducing some coding best practices, which include, but is not limited to: use constant values instead of magical numbers, i.e. NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE = 60 instead of just throwing 60 in your code; name your variables according to their meaning, i.e. people instead of result; use numpy strenghts, i.e. do not use numpy to hold strings, instead give meaning to your values through well named constants, and don't use for loops, use numpy's built-in functions to get the job done instead.
import numpy as np

# NUMBER_OF_DAYS = 50 #The number of times to repeat the run
INITIAL_PROBABILITY_OF_INFECTION = 0.1
NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE = 60

HEALTHY = 0
INFECTED = 1
ZOMBIE = 2

# Day one of the simulation
people = np.random.binomial(
    INFECTED,
    INITIAL_PROBABILITY_OF_INFECTION,
    NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
) 
print(people)
total_infections = np.sum(people == INFECTED)
print ("Number of Infected: ", total_infections)

# Create the matrix to track who is infected
people = np.where(
    people == INFECTED,
    ZOMBIE, # Value ZOMBIE (2) is broadcasted to the shape of people
    np.random.binomial(
        INFECTED,
        INITIAL_PROBABILITY_OF_INFECTION*total_infections,
        NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
    )
)
total_infections = np.sum(people == INFECTED))

print(people)
print("Number of Infected: ", total_infections)


